# Populate global Array from AsyncTask and call on onCreate

Tags: android, arrays, android-asynctask

Ever get those moments where you stare at a piece of code for an hour and still can't come up with an answer? Yeah that's me now.

I'm working on a final project for class and I can't get this one piece of code to work. It is absolutely crucial that it works, or else it defeats the purpose of the program. I even asked my professor for help... and he doesn't know how to help me solve the issue. I posted a similar problem a day ago but I want to re-ask in a different way to see if it helps (Sorry if its a re-post, I have no other source for help :/).

My problem is that I need to access array elements on my MainActivity after its populated inside an AsyncTask class. The array is defined globally but as soon as I try to access it's element or size, it crashes. I need to be able to call this array outside of AsyncTask.

I've searched for hours and tried "returning" the array from AsyncTask but it crashes as well.

Here is my code (I've included comments as to where it crashes):

```
public class PostsActivity extends Activity {

public static GlobalRates[] gr;
TextView view;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_posts);

    view = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

    BitRateFetcher br = new BitRateFetcher();
    br.execute();

    // !!! Line below crashes !!! 
    Log.i("BitRateFetcher", "Size from onCreate: " + gr.length);
}

private class BitRateFetcher extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, GlobalRates[]> {
    private static final String TAG = "BitRateFetcher";
    public String BIT_PAY_SERVER = "https://bitpay.com/api/rates";

    private ProgressDialog dialog;
    GlobalRates[] test;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        dialog = new ProgressDialog(PostsActivity.this);
        dialog.setMessage("Please Wait... Downloading Information");
        dialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected GlobalRates[] doInBackground(Void... params) {

        try {
            // Create an HTTP client
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet getBitRates = new HttpGet(BIT_PAY_SERVER);

            // Perform the request and check the status code
            HttpResponse bitRatesResponse = client.execute(getBitRates);

            StatusLine bitRatesStatus = bitRatesResponse.getStatusLine();

            if (bitRatesStatus.getStatusCode() == 200) {
                HttpEntity entity = bitRatesResponse.getEntity();
                InputStream content = entity.getContent();

                try {
                    // Read the server response and attempt to parse it as
                    // JSON
                    Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(content);
                    Gson gson = new Gson();

                    test = gson.fromJson(reader, GlobalRates[].class);

                    content.close();
                    entity.consumeContent();
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Failed to parse JSON due to: " + ex);
                    failedLoadingPosts();
                }

            } else {
                Log.e(TAG, "Server responded with status code: "
                        + bitRatesStatus.getStatusCode());
                failedLoadingPosts();
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Failed to send HTTP POST request due to: " + ex);
            failedLoadingPosts();
        }

        return test;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(GlobalRates[] test) {

        Log.i(TAG, "Test Size: " + test.length); // Returns 158
        gr = test;
        Log.i(TAG, "Gr Size: " + gr.length); // Returns 158

        if (dialog.isShowing()) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }

    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.posts, menu);
    return true;
}

private void failedLoadingPosts() {
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Toast.makeText(PostsActivity.this,
                    "Failed to load Posts. Have a look at LogCat.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
```

}

Here is the error Log:

```
04-21 20:30:01.954: E/AndroidRuntime(32595): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-21 20:30:01.954: E/AndroidRuntime(32595): Process: com.example.postsactivity, PID: 32595
04-21 20:30:01.954: E/AndroidRuntime(32595): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.postsactivity/com.example.postsactivity.PostsActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

My class partner and I are unsure as to how we can call the global array (gr) properly. I understand that onCreate is not going to wait for AsyncTask to finish. What can we do to get this to work? Thanks for the help and understanding. You guys can prove more useful than my professor...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is that you are accessing array of globalrates before it was initialized in your postExecute(). There are a lot of way to do this one of which is creating an interface or creating callbacks that waits for globalrate to be initialized after ur background thread is done.

- **Create a Interface**

---

```
public interface SampleInterface {

void globalResultBackground(GlobalRates[] gr);
}
```

- **implements the interface to ur activity**

---

```
 public class PostsActivity extends Activity implements SampleInterface
```

- **pass the interface to your asynctask**

---

```
//in the activity
BitRateFetcher br = new BitRateFetcher(this);
br.execute();

//in the asynctask class
SampleInterface si;
public BitRateFetcher(SampleInterface  si){
  this.si = si;
}
```

- **pass the result of the background thread to ur interface method**

---

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(GlobalRates[] test) {

    si.globalResultBackground(test);

    Log.i(TAG, "Test Size: " + test.length); // Returns 158
    gr = test;
    Log.i(TAG, "Gr Size: " + gr.length); // Returns 158

    if (dialog.isShowing()) {
        dialog.dismiss();
    }

}
```

- **in the activity where the you implemented the interface and generated the globalResultBackground method**

---

```
    @Override
public void globalResultBackground(GlobalRates[] gr) {
    //you can freely access the globalrates here because this is called when the
    //background thread is done

           Log.i("BitRateFetcher", "Size from onCreate: " + gr.length);


}
```

Comment: Do you know of any tutorials that demonstrates how to use callback features for this?

Comment: Thank you @user3444777. I implemented this and I am able to work off of it.

Answer (score 0):

Pass in your activity to the AsyncTask and directly access its gr in your `onPostExecute`

Sample code:

```
   private class BitRateFetcher extends AsyncTask {
     PostsActivity activity;
     ...
     public BitRateFetcher(PostsActivity activity){
       this.activity= activity;
     }
     ...
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(GlobalRates[] test) {
      activity.gr = ...
    }
   }
```

In PostsActivity,

```
   BitRateFetcher br = new BitRateFetcher(this);
```

Take care to `attach` and `reAttach` the activity to handle scenarios such as device rotations.

EDIT: Just noticed you've got a static, so you don't even need to pass in the activity. The same principle applies though.

Answer (score 0):

`GlobalRates[] gr` is public and static, so you dont really new `GlobalRates[] test`

simply replace every instance of `test` with `gr`:

```
 test = gson.fromJson(reader, GlobalRates[].class);
```

to

```
gr = gson.fromJson(reader, GlobalRates[].class);
```

if you need to access `gr` in Oncreate then move that logic to `postExecute`

```
Log.i("BitRateFetcher", "Size from onCreate: " + gr.length);
```